# A particular combinatorial identity

Tags: combinatorics

I have to do an estimate and I have to rewrite the following term:

$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} \frac{k}{n-k}
$$

How can I do?

Following the first answer given below, I deduce that this sum is exactly

$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k}k
$$

Adding and subtracting $1$, I deduce that this sum becomes $2^{n-1}-1$. It's right?

Comment: My answer uses probability to address this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A question is raised about this sum:
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k}k \tag 1
$$

Notice that $\dbinom n k \dfrac 1 {2^n}$ is the probability of getting exactly $k$ heads when a fair coin is tossed $n$ times.  Therefore, the *expected* number of heads is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n k \binom n k \frac 1 {2^n}. \tag 2
$$
Since the expected number is clearly $n/2$, one must conclude that the sum in $(2)$ is $n/2$.  One can then deduce things about the sum in $(1)$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose k}\frac{1}{n-k}$$
$$= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-k-1)!(n-k)}$$
$$= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\frac{1}{n}$$
$$= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$
$$= \frac{1}{n}(2^n - 1)$$

Comment: That's simpler than I was expecting. I'm a little curious what the a counting in two ways argument would look like.

Comment: @ZachStone Check this out. $2^n - 1$ is the number of ways of selecting a non-empty subset out of a set of $n$ numbers. Now, in order to select a non-empty subset of size $n-k (n>k\geq 0)$, there are $n$ ways in which I can select my first object and ${n-1 \choose n-k-1} = {n-1 \choose k}$ ways for selecting the rest, so we get $n {n-1 \choose k}$ ways. But there's no first object in a set and so, the first object could have been selected in $n-k$ ways. Thus, we need to divide by $n-k$ to get $\frac{n}{n-k} {n-1 \choose k}$. Sum over $k$ to get the required identity!

Answer (score 3):

$$\binom{n-1}{k} \frac{1}{n-k} = \frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-1-k)!} \frac{1}{n-k} = \frac{1}{n} \binom{n}{k}$$

$$\implies\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} \frac{1}{n-k} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} = \frac{2^n-1}{n}$$